# Finding better way of handling user session based data in angular/nodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, angular, redis

I have a stored procedure that take too much time to run as it internally does multiple joins on different tables, does group by, order by and then returns response to nodeJS server. The server than passes on this data received from mysql db to angular/client.

Because the client has to wait for too long to let http request complete. I was thinking of better approaches that will shorten the http request completion time.

Need suggestions on how can i handle or make the data in advance that a user will need later.Like adding a small cache database on server that will store user based data and clears out when user session is destroyed.If i go with this approach than which db will be best?

Or instead of having cache Db can i have a json file on server to store users data and use it?

Comment: If query the issue, perhaps improve your query efficiency? Only return data what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Having a json file on server would be too cumbersome to handle in cases like updation and query in my opinion. Please have a look at memory based dbs for caching purposes if the data doesnt change too often. My recommendation is [redis](https://redis.io) just because i have the best hands on it. However there are many other other options that you can find out with a quick serch like [memcached](https://memcached.org).

Caching strategy only works if the data you are caching doesnt change too quickly. You can explore different schema strategies for the same.